# itext placeholder on top of every new page

Tags: itext, placeholder, repeat

i try to print invoices on a pre defined template on a piece of paper.
Because of that template i need some placeholders before the invoice is printed to avoid overplap. Sometimes the invoices get a little bit longer so that i need a second invoice page. If the invoice just has one page everything works fine.

My issue:
If the invoice gets longer (second page) the placeholder has to be on the beginning of the second page as well. I was not able to figure out how to do this.

Here is how i do it on first page:

```
PdfPTable placeholderTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    placeholderTable.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPTable.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    placeholderTable.setWidthPercentage(91f);
    PdfPCell placeholderCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("      ", font4GroßFett));
    placeholderCell.setBorder(0);
    placeholderTable.addCell(placeholderCell);
    document.add(placeholderTable);
```

I tried a lot of things but especially i think the following is important (maybe i just use it in a wrong way)

```
writer.setPageEvent(new PdfPageEventHelper() {
    @Override
    public void onStartPage(final PdfWriter writer, final Document document) {
//add the placeholder here?
    }
    });
```

This seemed to be the best solution but i cant add elements to the document in this method (see offical documentation of itext)

My question is now: How can i set some placeholders (space) to the top of EVERY new page?
Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: why don't you simply set the margins of `Document` to prevent overlaps?

Comment: omg you are right. i didnt see that :( thats really embarrassing. thank you very much for post this simple answer :)